# Why using $controllerProvider.allowGlobals() is generally not recommended?

Tags: angularjs

When migrating from Angular 1.2 to 1.3, it's generally recommended that all your controllers are housed inside a module (otherwise they'll break) even though adding one line to the module's config can achieve the same thing:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$controllerProvider',function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

But it's not recommended as it may have implications in the future.

Is there another major reason why the latter method is not recommended?

Comment: Because it will pollute the global namespace. And it's considered as best practice to group controllers based on modules for organising purpose as well.

Comment: So it won't break your application in any way? It's not used just for aesthetical purposes?

Comment: It's used for aesthetically purpose to avoid collision with third party libraries and to have minimal footprint in the global namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to avoid unnecessarily polluting the global namespace, and to reduce the risk that other code, say from some non-Angular plugins, can interfer with yours.

Say you have a controller, `MyController` in the global scope. Some other bit of Javascript in that page can just set something like

```
window.MyController = window.alert;
```

which (depending on when the code runs) can break your Angular app.

Comment: This is what I was expecting. I wanted to know why it was not recommended when it can't break your app. This scenario shows that it indeed can. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use global functions as controllers, your functions are going to pollute the global namespace. There could be more chance of collision with other libraries.

That's the reason why in angular 1.3, its recommended to group controllers inside modules. In that way you won't be polluting the global namespace and also in terms of organising code, it's much modular as well. So it helps us to have minimal footprint in the global namespace.